Parameter 'hold_joints' has already been declared, parameter 'hold_joints' has already been declared
When I run my ros2 launch files to simulate my robot in gazebo I get this error:
Parameter 'hold_joints' has already been declared, parameter 'hold_joints' has already been declared

Which I believe causes my robot to fall over the spawn at Gazebo. However, I don't use a variable named hold_joints in my any file. After some reseach I have found that this variable is indeed related with gazebo_ros2_control library. Later I type the command below in the workspace to find where this variable is used,
grep -r hold_joints

And I get the following output from terminal:
grep: build/gazebo_ros2_control/CMakeFiles/gazebo_ros2_control.dir/src/gazebo_ros2_control_plugin.cpp.o: binary file matches
grep: build/gazebo_ros2_control/CMakeFiles/gazebo_hardware_plugins.dir/src/gazebo_system.cpp.o: binary file matches
grep: build/gazebo_ros2_control/libgazebo_ros2_control.so: binary file matches
grep: build/gazebo_ros2_control/libgazebo_hardware_plugins.so: binary file matches
grep: install/gazebo_ros2_control/lib/libgazebo_ros2_control.so: binary file matches
grep: install/gazebo_ros2_control/lib/libgazebo_hardware_plugins.so: binary file matches
src/gazebo_ros2_control/gazebo_ros2_control/CHANGELOG.rst:* Add `hold_joints` parameter (`#251 <https://github.com/ros-controls/gazebo_ros2_control/issues/251>`_)
src/gazebo_ros2_control/gazebo_ros2_control/src/gazebo_ros2_control_plugin.cpp:  bool hold_joints = true;  // default
src/gazebo_ros2_control/gazebo_ros2_control/src/gazebo_ros2_control_plugin.cpp:  if (sdf->HasElement("hold_joints")) {
src/gazebo_ros2_control/gazebo_ros2_control/src/gazebo_ros2_control_plugin.cpp:    hold_joints =
src/gazebo_ros2_control/gazebo_ros2_control/src/gazebo_ros2_control_plugin.cpp:      sdf->GetElement("hold_joints")->Get<bool>();
src/gazebo_ros2_control/gazebo_ros2_control/src/gazebo_ros2_control_plugin.cpp:      node_ros2->declare_parameter("hold_joints", rclcpp::ParameterValue(hold_joints));
src/gazebo_ros2_control/gazebo_ros2_control/src/gazebo_ros2_control_plugin.cpp:        impl_->model_nh_->get_logger(), "Parameter 'hold_joints' has already been declared, %s",
src/gazebo_ros2_control/gazebo_ros2_control/src/gazebo_ros2_control_plugin.cpp:        impl_->model_nh_->get_logger(), "Parameter 'hold_joints' has invalid name, %s", e.what());
src/gazebo_ros2_control/gazebo_ros2_control/src/gazebo_ros2_control_plugin.cpp:        impl_->model_nh_->get_logger(), "Parameter 'hold_joints' value is invalid, %s", e.what());
src/gazebo_ros2_control/gazebo_ros2_control/src/gazebo_ros2_control_plugin.cpp:        impl_->model_nh_->get_logger(), "Parameter 'hold_joints' value has wrong type, %s",
src/gazebo_ros2_control/gazebo_ros2_control/src/gazebo_system.cpp:  bool hold_joints_ = true;
src/gazebo_ros2_control/gazebo_ros2_control/src/gazebo_system.cpp:    this->dataPtr->hold_joints_ = this->nh_->get_parameter("hold_joints").as_bool();
src/gazebo_ros2_control/gazebo_ros2_control/src/gazebo_system.cpp:      "Parameter 'hold_joints' not initialized, with error %s", ex.what());
src/gazebo_ros2_control/gazebo_ros2_control/src/gazebo_system.cpp:      this->nh_->get_logger(), "Using default value: " << this->dataPtr->hold_joints_);
src/gazebo_ros2_control/gazebo_ros2_control/src/gazebo_system.cpp:      "Parameter 'hold_joints' not declared, with error %s", ex.what());
src/gazebo_ros2_control/gazebo_ros2_control/src/gazebo_system.cpp:      this->nh_->get_logger(), "Using default value: " << this->dataPtr->hold_joints_);
src/gazebo_ros2_control/gazebo_ros2_control/src/gazebo_system.cpp:      "Parameter 'hold_joints' has wrong type: %s", ex.what());
src/gazebo_ros2_control/gazebo_ros2_control/src/gazebo_system.cpp:      this->nh_->get_logger(), "Using default value: " << this->dataPtr->hold_joints_);
src/gazebo_ros2_control/gazebo_ros2_control/src/gazebo_system.cpp:    this->nh_->get_logger(), "hold_joints (system): " << this->dataPtr->hold_joints_ << std::endl);
src/gazebo_ros2_control/gazebo_ros2_control/src/gazebo_system.cpp:      } else if (this->dataPtr->is_joint_actuated_[j] && this->dataPtr->hold_joints_) {
src/gazebo_ros2_control/doc/index.rst:* ``<hold_joints>``: if set to true (default), it will hold the joints' position if their interface was not claimed, e.g., the controller hasn't been activated yet.

What could be the reason for this error?
This PR does look like the reason of my error but I am not sure how can I fix this.

I'll have a look, this sounds like a bug.

Are you sure that you use iron? The hold_joints parameter (the PR you linked) was not backported to iron.
Which version of gazebo_ros2_control have you installed? ros2 pkg xml gazebo_ros2_control -t version?
I just tried the gazebo_ros2_control_demos on a fresh iron workspace (but compiled gazebo_ros2_control from source). Can you test if the demos work with your setup?

Yes I have iron and the out of the command is: 0.7.1. I tried diff_drive example and got no errors.

From your grep output it seems that you compile gazebo_ros2_control from source. Then you use the wrong branch of the repo (0.7.1 is a rolling tag, 0.6.5 is the last iron tag).

Ahhh I understand know. How can I change the distrubition of repo?

See this table, use the iron branch if you compile gazebo_ros2_control from source for your iron distro.

Changing the branch of the dis did indeed fixed the problem. However I get a different error this time related to my urdf file. May I ask here or should I ask it under a new post?

Great. Please open a new question.

Thanks soo much for your help. Can I tag you to my new question.
